# How can I constrain the type assigned to a variable of type Type?

Tags: c#, types

*[Note: Edited to include requirement to create a collection of FollowUpEvent]*

I'm writing a calendaring system.  I have a base type of `CalendarEvent`, and a moderately complex hierarchy of descendant types (`AppointmentEvent`, `ReminderEvent`, `AppointmentInOfficeEvent`, etc).  I also want to create a schema structure that specifies for each event a list of follow-up events that should be created:

```
public class FollowUpEvent
{
    public Type EventType { get; set; };
    public int OffsetDays { get; set; };
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; };
}

static List<FollowUpEvent> EventsToAdd = new FollowUpEvent()
{
   new FollowUpEvent() { EventType = typeof(ReminderEvent), OffsetDays = 7, IsRequired = true },
   new FollowUpEvent() { EventType = typeof(ReminderEvent), OffsetDays = 14, IsRequired = false }
 }
```

The problem is that the `EventType` property will accept *any* object type, I would like to decoratively restrict it to `CalendarEvent` and its descendants.  I realize I could do this in the setter, but ideally I'd like to express it in the declaration of the property.

Is this possible?

(I come from a Delphi background, and I think what I'm looking for is the equivalent of the `MyType = class of CalendarEvent` declaration.)

Comment: Why not declare public CalendarEvent EventType?

Comment: Make the class generic, where T : CalendarEvent, and set EventType's type to T.

Comment: @NWard I think Lustig does not want to point to the actual event. He only wants to store the type of the event ( I don't know why on the otherhand)

Comment: Because the follow-up system is a schema that instructs a worflow component to construct the appropriate follow-up instances.

Comment: @Magus: I need a list of these (`List<FollowUpEvent> FollowUpSpecs`) and the list will be polymorphic with respect to descendants of CalendarEvent.  If I do `List<FollowUpEvent<CalendarEvent>>`, will that hold a list of typed follow-up events (I think that might be a solution).

Comment: If you do it like the current answer, no, because T will be the type declared for the list. If you do it the way I suggested, you'll need an instance rather than the Type in order to instantiate which is not great, but you can call GetType on it and get the sub type with no problem. No matter what, this will be messy. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If all you are doing is specifying which type you need, why not have a private dictionary of (for example) <int, type>, a public enum where you specify the mapping, and a get-only Type property which retrieves the appropriate type from the dict?

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but he seems to want to restrict the type. That's the major point of the question. I'd do it that way though.

Comment: @NWard: That's certainly a solution, but it seems like a substantial duplication of effort when it seems to me (naively, I'm beginning to guess) that the type system ought to be able to provide the same functionality.  I know that eventually (where "eventually" means within eight weeks) I'll add some classes and forget to update the dictionary.

Comment: What if you make a constructor for FollowUpEvent that takes a CalendarEvent? `public FollowUpEvent(CalendarEvent event) { EventType = typeof(event) }`

Comment: That was essentially my suggestion, though note that it'd need to be `.GetType()` because it's called on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the following makes sense but if you do not want to store the actual `CalendarEvent` object it will work:

```
public class FollowUpEvent<T> where T: CalendarEvent
{
    public Type EventType { get 
                            {
                              return this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]
                              // OR
                              // return typeof(T)
                            }
                          }
    public int OffsetDays { get; set; };
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; };
}
```

Comment: You can replace `this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` with `typeof(T)`.

Comment: This gets me part of the way (all the way through what I wrote in the original question), but I cannot then create a static `List<FollowUpEvent<CalendarEvent>>` initialized with (for instance) `new FollowUpEvent<ReminderEvent>() {OffsetDays = 7, IsRequired = true}`

Comment: maybe just declaring an enumeration to describe the type of the event can be a solution.

Comment: @LarryLustig: `List<T>` is not, and cannot be, covariant on the type parameter. If you can switch to a pure `IEnumerable<T>` solution, that should work. Alternatively, you'll need to extract a non-generic interface or base-class for the `FollowUpEvent<T>` class.

Comment: @RichardDeeming: Off to research the first suggestion.  I definitely don't want a type-specific set of FollowUpEvent classes, that would be too much duplication of effort.

Answer (score -2):

Have EventType of type BaseEvent from which all the other event types can inherit so that you can restrict the accpeted types.

Comment: Yes, that's my question -- *how* to restrict the accepted types.